# Are Vulkan renderpasses thread local in multi-threading rendering

Tags: 3d, game-engine, vulkan

I'm currently moving my game to Vulkan. In my game, I have multiple worker threads to generate drawcalls. Each worker thread has its own command buffer. As render pass begin/end pair need to be within command buffer begin/end pair, so I would think render passes need to be thread local. Is that correct?

If that's the case, my second question is that how can I share pipeline objects among worker threads?

I currently maintain a global pipeline object map, for each drawcall, worker threads generate a key based on render states, shaders and other related information. But because render pass is also needed for creating pipeline object, if render pass is thread local, that would make pipeline object thread local. In this case, how can I share pipeline object among different worker threads?

For sure I've got something wrong, but I can't figure out what that is. please help out.

Comment: @Elletlar: This is not a "my code is broken" question. He's describing what he's thinking about doing.

Answer (score 4):

Making things thread-local is one way to achieve the goal, but you can use Vulkan objects from any thread as long as you properly do your own (i.e. external) synchronization.

Any object that is a parameter to a Vulkan command will be read. Any object marked "externally synchronized" will be written. Rest is just synchronizing write–read\write hazards as is usual in multi-threaded programming.

Many Vulkan objects are constant, and I think `VkRenderPass` is one of those, which would simplify things. I.e. only place `VkRenderPass` would be marked "externally synchronized" (i.e. write hazard) is its destructor.

> If that's the case, my second question is that how can I share pipeline objects among worker threads?

Same rules apply to `VkPipeline` objects. Unlike `vkCmd*` commands, creation commands (`vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`) do not hold on to the `VkRenderPass` object:

> A `VkRenderPass` object passed as a parameter to create another object is not further accessed by that object after the duration of the command it is passed into.

And in any case they only read it (no "externally synchronized"). And read–read "hazard" need no synchronization. So you do not need to worry about `VkRenderPass`es when migrating `VkPipeline` to a different thread.

Comment: Aha! That clears everything for me! I'm going to query and use render passes and pipeline objects among all my worker threads, then provide my feedback here! Thank you very much!

Comment: So I did the test. I made render passes and pipeline objects shared among worker threads. But I got error messages: vkCmdBeginRenderPass(): It is invalid to issue this call inside an active render pass. I think it's because the same render pass is within a begin/end pair from one thread while other threads trying to call begin() on it. If a render pass can not be used concurrently among threads, for the same RT layout, I need to have different render passes for different threads, thus I need different pipeline objects... Is that the case? Is that how people do multi-threading in Vulkan?

Comment: @user10130181 Are you not calling `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` accidentally twice on the same command buffer?